# issue with a sort method (C)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm having issues with a sort method I wrote. It is supposed to find the max value, and replace the last value in the array with the max (and move that value to where the last value was).

I've ran gdb, and it looks like the `if` statement always executes, and for some reason `max = values[0]` always sets max to 0.  Granted I am very new to C so I might be wrong about what is going on.

```
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    int max; //hold the max value through the iteration
    int replaced; //to hold the value at the end of the array
    int replacedhash; //to hold the location of the max value
    do 
    {
        replaced = values[n];
        max = values[0]; //reset max to 0 for new iteration
        for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++)
        {
            //check if the next value is larger,
            //then update max and replacedhash if it is
            if (max < values[i]) 
            {
                max = values[i];
                replacedhash = i;
            }
        }
        values[replacedhash] = replaced; //next three lines swap the values
        n--;
        values[n] = max;    
    } while (n!=0);
}
```

And I would use this by running:

```
int main() {
    int test[] = {3,5,2,5,6,100,4,46};
    sort(test, 8);
    printarray(test, 8);
}
```

Comment: 1) should be `replaced = values[n-1];`

Comment: `replacedhash` is initialized if `(max < values[i])` is false

Comment: @sharth; Hmmm. Didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error 1: `replaced = values[n-1];`

Your example in the problem statement is:

```
int test[] = {3,5,2,5,6,100,4,46};
sort(test, 8);
```

So you'll then look at `test[8]`, which is undefined behavior

### Error 2: `replacedhash`

`replacedhash` will be uninitialized if the first element of the array is the max. And it will probably have an incorrect value on later loops when the first element is the max.

### My thoughts:

It appears to me that you've overcomplicating the code. You probably should just find the **index** in the array that has the maximum value, and then do the swap. It'll be simpler.

```
void sort(int values[], int n) {
    do {
        // Find index of maximum value
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            if (values[max] < values[i])
                max = i;

        // Swap
        int temp = values[max];
        values[max] = values[n-1];
        values[n-1] = temp;

        n--;
    } while (n != 0);
}
```

Comment: the commented out 'test' is different than the one I've been writing, so values[8] isn't part of the issue.  I do appreciate the slimmed down version, makes much more sense.

Comment: FWIW: `while (n > 1)` instead of `do...while (n != 0)` saves one useless pass (and deals with the stupid case of `n < 1` to start with !).  Also: `int i=1` to avoid one pointless comparison.  And: it's possible to avoid the swap if the `value[n-1]` is, in fact, the largest value, by doing one less comparision in the `for` loop, and doing the final comparison in an `if` which skips the swap.